# Multiple users to run the same script

Tags: vbscript, userid

I have a VBScript that works coping 1 (one) file from network location to Users C:. I have 11 persons that need to run this script.

What do I use for a wild card for multiple user login names so I don't have to create several scripts for each and every person?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to obtain the account name of the currently logged-in user, for instance by expanding the respective environment variable:

```
>>> Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>>> WScript.Echo sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
jsmith
```

or via a `WshNetwork` object:

```
>>> Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
>>> WScript.Echo net.UserName
jsmith
```

or via WMI:

```
>>> Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
>>> For Each obj In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem") : _
WScript.Echo obj.UserName : _
Next
VM01\jsmith
```

Comment: this is the script i currently have how do i insert your reasoning into it?

Comment: Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CopyFile "K:\Eng_Config\Sean\DS Stamp Macro\Stamp\*.pdf", "C:\Users\sebuiln\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\10.0\Stamps\", True

Comment: Assign the username to a variable and concatenate that variable with the rest of the path: `"K:\Eng_Config\" & username & "\DS Stamp Macro\Stamp*.pdf"`